# Django: Catching Integrity Error vs qs.exists() which one is more efficient?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Two ways to check whether same data exists or not:

**1**

```
try:
    MyModel.objects.create(
        field1=field1_value,
        field2=field1_value,
    )
except IntegrityError:
    # doing something
```

**2**

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(field1=field1_value, field2=field2_value)
if qs.exists():
    # doing something
```

I wonder which one is more desirable way to check integrity.

Comment: An integrity error can mean other things than only the fact that there exists already such field. For example an illegal foreign key, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try-Except is less *efficient* than if-else statements...but it's more *desirable* due to it's versatility and the points below...so the answer really depends on your use-case...if you're trying to run a high performance real-time application if-else is better, but if you're writing a general purpose library where you dont know what Failures could occur or how the user would want to handle it then Try-Except is superior.

You have access to [Finally](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Exceptions#Recovering_and_continuing_with_finally) with Try-Except blocks.

Except won't stop code from halting when an error is hit, which is especially preferable if you're handling a narrow exception type.

Also you dont have to predict when the exception will occur in the codeblock, like you would have to in case of if else statements. That is..

```
try:
    # do some things before
    MyModel.objects.create(
        field1=field1_value,
        field2=field1_value,
    )
    # do some things after
except IntegrityError:
    # catch the exception regardless of where in the Try Block the failure occured
```

However in case of if statements you have to predict that the point of failure is going to be at the `MyModels.objects.create()` call, which is a potential mistake that can be easily avoided.